# Почему не удается сделать замену(транслит) букв в названии файлов?

Tags: php

Есть папка с файлами. Хочу вывести на экран название файлов выполнив транслитерацию букв:

```
    function translit2($in) {
        $trans1 = array('«','»', "'",'`',',',' ',"?","!",":",";",".","Ё","Ж","Ч","Ш","Щ","Э","Ю","Я","ё","ж","ч","ш","щ","э","ю","я","А","Б","В","Г","Д","Е","З","И","Й","К","Л","М","Н","О","П","Р","С","Т","У","Ф","Х","Ц","Ь","Ы","а","б","в","г","д","е","з","и","й","к","л","м","н","о","п","р","с","т","у","ф","х","ц","ь","ы");
        $trans2 = array('','', '-','-','-','-',"","","","",".","JO","ZH","CH","SH","SCH","Je","Jy","Ja","jo","zh","ch","sh","sch","je","jy","ja","A","B","V","G","D","E","Z","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","R","S","T","U","F","H","C","","Y","a","b","v","g","d","e","z","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","r","s","t","u","f","h","c","","y");
        return str_replace($trans1,$trans2,$in);
    }


 if ($handle = opendir(".")) {
    while ($entry = readdir($handle)) {
        if (is_file($entry)) {
            echo translit2($entry)."<br>";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
 }
```

В итоге ничего не заменяет, кроме пробелов. Как это обойти? 
P.S. функция транслита работает, проверял.

Comment: Потому что кодировка имени файла не совпадает с кодировкой кода php. Отсюда - скрипт не видит кириллических букв в именах файлов.

Comment: @Visman , точно! Спасибо!!!